# removing columns from a text file

Tags: c#, text-files

I am trying to convert biometric data into something useful such as getting their total late in coming data, I've got a python code from years ago and I have just started learning C# today but I'm at a loss on how'd I convert this into a running code the very core of my problem is on this image [image]

here's my python code that i'd at least wish to convert into a working C# code

```
gmt = strftime("%m-%d-%Y %I:%M:%S %p")#reading the local time
with open('AGL_001.txt', 'r') as fin:
    data = fin.read().splitlines(True)
with open('backup/converted '+gmt+'.txt', 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines(data[1:])
with open('converted.txt', 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines(data[1:])
filepath = 'converted.txt'#read the text file the system created
with open(filepath) as fp:  
   line = fp.readline()
   while line:
    lines = tuple(line.split()) #split them and make them tuple in order to select them one by one
    line = fp.readline()

    user_id = lines[2] #declare variables

    l_date = lines[5]
    l_date_split = tuple(l_date.split("/"))#splitting l_date so we can extract month and year

    l_time = lines[6]
    gmt = strftime("%m %d %Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z\n")#reading the local time
    gmt = tuple(gmt.split())#splitting whatever the local time, so we can combine them again lol
    time_zone = (gmt[2] +"/"+ gmt[0]) #combining the split data (what an idiot) wasting time to split then combining
    date_split = (l_date_split[0]+"/"+l_date_split[1])#also the splitted data from l_date also combining it here as well

    if(gmt[1]>="16"): #checking if the local date is greater than 16 because the cut-off is 15 then we add limiters so we can limit
        limiter = "16" #the number of days to be written
        limiter2 = "31"
    else:
        limiter = "0"
        limiter2 = "15"
    if(time_zone == date_split):#check if time_zone is equal to l_date_split example time_zone = 2020/01 and l_date_split = 2019/01 that wont work
        if(limiter <= l_date_split[2] <= limiter2):
            logs = [(None, user_id, l_date, l_time)]
            print(logs)
            #cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO logs VALUES (?,?,?,?)', logs)
```

i tried .split() and arrays but i can't get it to work

Comment: We're not a code writing service. What have you tried?

Comment: ah yes i'm aware, what i actually needed is the part where i can separate the data from the text file so i can access it, what the python code above does is split data and somehow make it an array so i can access them one by one and put them in a database, though i said what i tried but to repeat it i tried split together with arrays but can't get it to work.

Comment: Add the c# code you tried. Perhaps is just a small correction...

Comment: The data is fixed width data.  You can use the string method substring to get part of a string.  Use  line = line.Substring(0,20) to get the first 20 character on each line.

Comment: You possibly just need this regex `^(?<digit>\d)\s+(?<timestamp>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})`. Then you can easily parse out the date

Comment: If you are in Linux you could probably even use awk or sed. Using C# though, I'd just use fixed indices into each line (using ReadOnlySpan<char>) to extract the cell data.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [File.ReadAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=net-7.0), [File.WriteAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=net-7.0), [StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=net-7.0), [StreamWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=net-7.0), [FileStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=net-7.0)

Comment: [String.Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-7.0), [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-7.0), [String.Trim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-7.0), [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-7.0), [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0)

Comment: i will look into each of these comments thank you guys

Comment: @Enigmativity i'm quite curious about the regex, how'd you get it to work can you give me a sample code?

Comment: @LouieJayOrellanaJayme - `File.ReadLines("filenamehere").Select(x => Regex.Match(x, @"^(?<digit>\d)\s+(?<timestamp>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})")).Where(x => x.Success)`

Comment: @LouieJayOrellanaJayme - Please write you're own code with that as your base. When you get stuck add it to the question.